# iframe tag in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I am using an iframe tag in my asp.net page. When I place any other controls in that 
page, after running the page except iframe tag no other controls displaying in that page.

Comment: can you paste the markup. It is quite hard to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have closing tag for the iframe, it should be like this:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Before Iframe" /> <br />
        <iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2"
            runat="server" Text="After Iframe" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Note that google.com and yahoo.com may not work in iframe because of restrictions from google and yahoo. Use your site url or a less popular one.

Answer (score 1):

Are You putting your controls inside the `iframe` tag? Content You put over there will only be shown by (really) old browsers that don't support iframes. You need to make a second page and have the iframe load it (`src` attribute)

If the controls are outside the iframe, it *should* work fine. If it isn't, there must be a problem with the markup, like unclosed tags.

Example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server">Outside IFRAME</asp:Literal><br />
    <iframe src="OtherPage.aspx">
        Your browser does not support IFRAMEs.
    </iframe><br />
    <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server">Outside IFRAME</asp:Literal>
</form>
```